# Can't get ubuntu to recognize my network adaptor on ASUS TP300l and I couldn't find a driver for it on the internet

Tags: drivers

I'm trying ubuntu on my TP300l ASUS laptop but it is not recognizing the network driver, so I can't even find drivers for other devices and I searched on the Internet but couldn't find any drivers for linux.

What can I do to solve that problem?

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.